# Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

I am kind of new to PHP, and very new to MySQLi and **I am trying to insert a row into the database comprised of 5 variables.**

```
if($_POST['submit']) {
            $title = mysqli_escape_string($_POST['title']);
            $content = $_POST['content'];
            $author = $_SESSION['fullname'];
            $publishedtime = time();
            $pageID = $_POST['pageid'];
            $connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

            if ($connection->errno) {
                printf("Connection failed: %s\n", $connection->error);
                exit();
            }

            $author = $_SESSION['fullname'];
            $publishedtime = time();
            $q = "INSERT INTO posts (title, content, author, publishedtime, pageID) VALUES ('".$title."', '".$content."', '".$author."', '".$publishedtime."', '".$pageID."')";

            if (!$dbc->query($q)) {
                echo "INSERT failed: (" . $dbc->errno . ") " . $dbc->error;
            }    
            echo "Newest user id = ",$dbc->insert_id;

            $connection->close();

        }
        else {
            addPostForm();
        }
```

and I get these errors:

> Warning: mysqli_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /admin/manage.php on line 11
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /admin/manage.php on line 27

I can read the database fine but can't insert into it.

Thanks

Comment: All the errors are reported just fine. Read and diagnose.

Comment: I don't care about the mysqli warning, I can figure that out probably, but I don't know what the error means otherwise I would diagnose it. I googled and every person with the error got a different fix and of the ones I found they either didn't work for me or weren't applicable. That's why I posted it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `real_escape_string` after creating your `mysqli` object, you can just use

```
$connection->real_escape_string($_POST['title'])
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

---

As for the query error... Where does `$dbc` come from?! You'll want to use:

```
$connection->query(...);
```